# Getting the combined height of several elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to get the combined height of several elements without iterating over them?   Note that `<li>` elements might have different height.

The following does not work, and will only return a value (not combined) if slice starts at zero.

```
$('#myList li').slice(4,8).count();
```

Comment: No, what is the `count`? a plugin?

Comment: Oops, didn't mean count, but height().

Comment: No it is'nt! You'll have to iterate and add up the elements heights.

Comment: Okay, didn't think so but wasn't sure.  Thank you.